# avoid printing points in xsim

Tags: xsim

I'm trying to migrate from `exsheets` to `xsim`, and I was wondering if there is an easy way to tell `xsim` not to print the points of the exercises (I'm thinking about a parameter added within `xsimsetup`). I used to do this in `exsheets` with something along the lines of

```
\ifdefined\exam 5 \else 0 \fi
```

but this is not working anymore.

Also, I can't find something analogous to

```
type = exam
```

in order to get "Question" rather than "Exercise" (yes, I minor thing but anyway...). Is that gone?

Cheers.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: Which template (in the xsim sense) do you use for exercises? Did you try defining your own template without printing points?

Comment: No, I didn't...I'm new to `xsim` and I was an un-advanced user of `exsheets` where I didn't need this. I'll take a look.

Comment: If you do not want points at all, replace ``\begin{question}[ID=001, points=10]`` with ``\begin{question}[ID=001]``. If you set a template, something like ``\GetExercisePropertyT{points}{}`` might work (untested).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks PatrickT, that did the trick!!

For future reference, in the preamble I added

```
\xsimsetup{                                                                                           
    solution/print = true,
    exercise/template = nopoints,
    solution/template = nopoints
}
\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{nopoints}{%                                                       
    \subsection*
    {%
        \XSIMmixedcase{\GetExerciseName}\nobreakspace
        \GetExerciseProperty{counter}%
        \IfInsideSolutionF
        {%
        \GetExercisePropertyT{subtitle}
        { {\normalfont\itshape\PropertyValue}}%
        }%
    }
    \GetExercisePropertyT{points}{}%
}
{}
```

(the template is simply the default template with the change suggested by PatrickT).

Cheers.

Comment: Leaving `\GetExercisePropertyT{points}{}` away completely would be even easier